# PyQt5.How can I change Table's content?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I am working on a customers record program,that will be used in beauty saloon.

My dialog window fill the table widget pretty well,but data is only attached to exact time,but not to the date.I simply have only one page in my table. So I need my table widget to be connected with the calendar, so I can choose the date by clicking on a number in my calendar and table fills with data for that exact day. And when I choose the date in dialog in "setDateTime" widget, data should be placed in the table for that exact day. Is it even possible to accomplish it with table widget? Perhaps the data that I create in dialog window should be saved and then be used by tablewidget.

So I have my main window[image]
Here is full code for it

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(860, 803)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.calendarWidget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.calendarWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 331, 191))
    self.calendarWidget.setObjectName("calendarWidget")
    self.addclient = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.addclient.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 350, 331, 81))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Verdana")
    font.setPointSize(10)
    self.addclient.setFont(font)
    self.addclient.setObjectName("addclient")
    self.uslugi = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.uslugi.setEnabled(True)
    self.uslugi.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 270, 331, 81))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Verdana")
    font.setPointSize(10)
    self.uslugi.setFont(font)
    self.uslugi.setObjectName("uslugi")
    self.mastera = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.mastera.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 190, 331, 81))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Verdana")
    font.setPointSize(10)
    self.mastera.setFont(font)
    self.mastera.setObjectName("mastera")
    self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 0, 521, 781))
    self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(25)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(3, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(4, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(5, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(6, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(7, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(8, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(9, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(10, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(11, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(12, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(13, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(14, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(15, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(16, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(17, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(18, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(19, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(20, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(21, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(22, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(23, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(24, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
    item.setFont(font)
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(4, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(5, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(6, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(7, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(8, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(9, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(10, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(11, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(12, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(13, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(14, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(15, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(16, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(17, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(18, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(19, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(20, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(21, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(22, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(23, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(24, 0, item)
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
```

Dialog window
[image]

```
class Ui_Dialog(object):
def setupUi(self, Dialog):
    Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
    Dialog.resize(281, 176)
    self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Dialog)
    self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 10, 71, 22))
    self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Dialog)
    self.comboBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 71, 22))
    self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
    self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
    self.dateTimeEdit = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit(Dialog)
    self.dateTimeEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 194, 22))
    self.dateTimeEdit.setObjectName("dateTimeEdit")
    self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
    self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 91, 16))
    self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
    self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
    self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 110, 113, 20))
    self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
    self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
    self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 90, 121, 16))
    self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
    self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
    self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 110, 113, 20))
    self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
    self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
    self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 111, 16))
    self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 140, 111, 23))
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
    self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 140, 111, 23))
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")

    self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Новый клиент"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Dialog", "Услуга"))
    self.comboBox_2.setItemText(0, _translate("Dialog", "Мастер"))
    self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Дата и время:"))
    self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Контактный номер:"))
    self.label_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Имя клиента"))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Добавить клиента"))
    self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Отмена записи"))
if __name__ == "__main__":
import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
ui = Ui_Dialog()
ui.setupUi(Dialog)
Dialog.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is all the functions

```
import sys
from interface import *
from dialog import *
from Services import *
from MastersList import *

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        # cancel
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.reject)
        # accept
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.accept)
        self.dateTimeEdit.setDisplayFormat("d/M/yy hh:mm")

    def data(self):
        master = self.comboBox_2.currentText()
        service = self.comboBox.currentText()
        name = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        contact_number = self.lineEdit.text()
        time = self.dateTimeEdit.time()
        return master, service, name, contact_number, time

class Services(QtWidgets.QDialog,Ui_SForm):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

class Masters(QtWidgets.QDialog,Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.addclient.clicked.connect(self.onAddClient)
        self.mastera.clicked.connect(self.AddMaster)
        self.uslugi.clicked.connect(self.AddService)
        self.masters = Masters(self)
        self.services = Services(self)
        self.dialog = Dialog(self)

        proxy = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        proxy.setSourceModel(self.masters.tableWidget.model())
        proxy.setFilterRegExp(".*\S.*")
        self.dialog.comboBox_2.setModel(proxy)

        proxy2 = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        proxy2.setFilterRegExp(".*\S.*")
        proxy2.setSourceModel(self.services.tableWidget.model())
        self.dialog.comboBox.setModel(proxy2)
        self.dialog.comboBox.setModelColumn(0)

    def AddService(self):
        self.services.show()

    def AddMaster(self):
        self.masters.show()

    def onAddClient(self):
        if self.dialog.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            master, service, name, contact_number, time = self.dialog.data()
            row = int(QtCore.QTime(8, 0).secsTo(time) / (30 * 60))
            if row >= 0:
                for k, text in enumerate([master, service, name, contact_number]):
                    self.tableWidget.setItem(row, k + 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(text))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What happens if the item already exists and you want to add it, is the item updated?

Comment: Yes,it should be updated

Comment: @eyllanesc so,I think it could be achieved without some sort of pages, the table just need to change items depending on a date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible to implement the logic with the model provided by `QTableWidget` since each time you add a term you increase the memory of the application. In your comment you say that you want to change the items, if you do that delete the previous data so you could not use it again.

The correct thing is to save the information in a file that can be a .xml, .csv, etc and then with some method to filter the information and display it, in addition to creating a method to update the data. A simple way to implement the above is to use a database, and a good option in this case is to use sqlite, in it you must create the table:

```
def createConnection():
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName(QDir.current().filePath("data.db"))
    if not db.open():
        QMessageBox.critical(None, "Cannot open database",
                             "Unable to establish a database connection.\n"
                             "This example needs SQLite support. Please read "
                             "the Qt SQL driver documentation for information how "
                             "to build it.\n\n"
                             "Click Cancel to exit.",
                             QMessageBox.Cancel)
        return False

    query = QSqlQuery()
    query.exec("create table IF NOT EXISTS product(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
               "date_and_time DATETIME, master VARCHAR(140), service VARCHAR(140), name VARCHAR(140),"
               "Contact_Number VARCHAR(140))")

    return True
```

Then create a model that handles that type of data, Qt offers the `QSqlTableModel` class that handles that type of data. But for it to work correctly you must have a pre-set date format and in your case it is observed that it is 8:00, 8:30, ..., 20:00, ie hours from 8:00 to 20:00 spaced every half hour, for this we must validate the entry and round it to the correct values, in addition if there is only the data must be updated but must be created.

```
self.model = QSqlTableModel()
self.model.setTable("product")
```

---

```
def onAddClient(self):
    client = ClientDialog(self)
    proxy = QSortFilterProxyModel()
    proxy.setSourceModel(self.view.model())
    proxy.setFilterRegExp(".*\S.*")
    client.masterCombo.setModel(proxy)
    client.masterCombo.setModelColumn(2)
    client.serviceCombo.setModel(proxy)
    client.serviceCombo.setModelColumn(3)

    if client.exec_() == ClientDialog.Accepted:
        master, service, name, contact_number, datetime = client.data()
        time = datetime.time()
        if QTime(8, 0) > time or QTime(20, 0) < time:
            return
        datetime = QDateTime(datetime.date(), QTime(8, 0).addSecs(30*60*int(QTime(8, 0).secsTo(time)/(30*60))))
        print(datetime)
        query = QSqlQuery()
        query.prepare("SELECT * FROM product WHERE date_and_time=:date_and_time")
        query.bindValue(":date_and_time", datetime)
        query.exec_()
        if query.next():
            id = query.value(0)
            query.prepare("UPDATE product SET master= :master, service=:service, name=:name, "
                          "Contact_Number=:contact_number where id = :id")
            query.bindValue(":id", id)
        else:
            query.prepare("INSERT INTO product(date_and_time, master, service, name, Contact_Number)"
                          "VALUES (:date_and_time, :master, :service, :name, :contact_number)")
            query.bindValue(":date_and_time", datetime)
        query.bindValue(":master", master)
        query.bindValue(":service", service)
        query.bindValue(":name", name)
        query.bindValue(":contact_number", contact_number)
        if not query.exec_():
            query.lastError().text()
        self.onSelectDay(self.calendarWidget.selectedDate())
```

With the previous model will only fill the boxes that have data, but in your case you want all a table of 25 rows for it is created the following proxy:

```
class CustomProxyModel(QIdentityProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, c, *args, **kwargs):
        QIdentityProxyModel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.mapping = [None] * 25
        self.c = c

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return 25

    def index(self, row, column, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return self.createIndex(row, column)

    def mapToSource(self, proxyIndex):
        if proxyIndex.isValid():
            r = self.mapping[proxyIndex.row()]
            if r is not None:
                return self.sourceModel().index(r, proxyIndex.column())
        return QModelIndex()

    def mapFromSource(self, sourceIndex):
        if sourceIndex.isValid():
            return self.createIndex(self.mapping.index(sourceIndex.row()), sourceIndex.column())
        return QModelIndex()

    def data(self, proxyIndex, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not proxyIndex.isValid():
            return QVariant()

        val = QIdentityProxyModel.data(self, proxyIndex, role)
        if proxyIndex.column() == self.c:
            if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
                return QTime(8, 0).addSecs(30 * 60 * proxyIndex.row()).toString("h:mm")
        return val

    def flags(self, index):
        return QIdentityProxyModel.flags(self, index) | Qt.ItemIsEnabled

    def fixModel(self):
        self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
        self.mapping = [None] * 25
        for r in range(self.sourceModel().rowCount()):
            ix = self.sourceModel().index(r, self.c)
            data = self.sourceModel().data(ix)
            self.mapping[
                QTime(8, 0).secsTo(QDateTime.fromString(data.replace("T", " "), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.zzz").time()) // (
                    30 * 60)] = r
        self.layoutChanged.emit()
```

This table must be updated every time you click on a date to do so it connects the clicked signal and filters the data:

```
self.calendarWidget.clicked.connect(self.onSelectDay)
```

---

```
def onSelectDay(self, date):
    start = QDateTime(date)
    stop = start.addDays(1)
    self.model.setFilter("date_and_time BETWEEN DATETIME('{}') AND DATETIME('{}')".
                         format(start.toString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.zzz"),
                                stop.toString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.zzz")))
    self.model.select()
    self.proxy.fixModel()
```

Since with the QTableWidget could not implement the logic I created the GUI from scratch having the same functionalities that you have placed except the dialogs of Master and Service.

The complete code can be found on the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/46895943)

Comment: It works exactly as I imagine,but I'm little confused :D I've been trying to add my service and masters dialogs to this code,but it does not work,could you try to integrate these? I added both of them at the end of the post

Comment: @akeg Have you connected the buttons to the functions that call the dialogues ?, take your time and analyze, is a way to strengthen the knowledge. :P

Comment: Yeap,they are connected now and dialogues are showing when I clicking the buttons,but comboboxes are dont fills with items from dialogues,maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: @akeg 
Today I do not have time, maybe tomorrow I will help you, I would like you to try to solve this problem so that you learn some things because other problems will come and you will not be able to solve it.

Comment: okay sure. I made a few changes in main.py(edited the post),tried to integrate my dialogues there,but it didnt work out for me

Comment: Do not add those things to your question since it does not have to do with the initial question, keep in mind that later they will review others and they will not understand anything. You have tests and if it works, I upload it to github and share the link so I can help you tomorrow, but what I want from you is that I try to solve your problem so that it learns.

Comment: Where can I put my updated code, so you can check it? Still did not make it work :c

Comment: https://github.com/akeg/stackoverflow-project/tree/master
first time working with github,hope did everything right :D

Comment: Another option is to use crontab, but give it time to load your desktop or rather your desktop manager since if it is loaded any GUI will not show and crash.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157508/discussion-between-eyllanesc-and-akeg).

Comment: Realized that did almost everything wrong, I thing I close to solution,so please,check my code, I edited it just now. There is ServiceDialog class in main.py that i worked on Can you tell me what is the problem there? after I push the button whola application just closing

Comment: Your sql code is incorrect, I also recommend reading it is a QAbstractProxyModel task, it is silly just copy and paste code without analyzing or understanding.

Comment: Hello. Can you explain how to build this into .exe with sqlite support? I tried many different variants and seen couple examples,but non of them work for me.
Here is one of them https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47013889/build-a-exe-file-from-py-with-sqlite-database. thank you in advance.