# Build a .exe file from .py with SQLite database

Tags: python, sqlite, exe, cx-freeze

Program makes appointments and places them into schedule which are written in QsQLite database. The program runs from .py but I need it to be in .exe. 
I have used cx_Freeze to create an .exe file, but the program does not generate the SQLite database.
So here is my setup file:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os
import sys

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files\Python35\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files\Python35\tcl\tk8.6'


build_exe_options = {"packages": [
  'os','sys','sqlite3'], 'include_files': [os.path.join(sys.base_prefix, 'DLLs', 'sqlite3.dll'), 'main.py','util.py','data.db']}

setup(
    name = "Eclients",
    version = "0.1",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("main.py")]
)
```

But database can't be opened

So,how it can be solved?

Comment: @MrGumble,edited my question, I solve the TCL error,but database still cant be opened,do you have any other thoughts why it is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this problem by copying the whole 'sqldrivers' folder from `C:\Program Files\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\plugins`to main.exe directory.

Answer (score 1):

You are not including your SQLite database file in the `include_files` statement. See the documentation: http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#using-data-files

A better solution, however, would be to provide an option to create the missing database file when needed. This would allow the database's SCHEMA be defined within your script, and be kept consistent with your programme logic. If it needs populating with data, this might however be a less optimal solution.